# please help installing missing pkgs

Tags: apt, 10.04

I tried to install exploration software for multirobot but i got many errors regarding dependency problems
i tried several times to install them but I couldnot
could anyone help me please 
thanks

```
nao@nao-Lab:~/Downloads$ sudo dpkg -i mrxt_1.1-1_i386.deb
[sudo] password for nao: 
(Reading database ... 263936 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack mrxt_1.1-1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking mrxt (1.1-1) over (1.1-1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mrxt:
 mrxt depends on libopencv-highgui2.3.
 mrxt depends on libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.7.0~beta1); however:
  Package libqtcore4:i386 is not installed.
 mrxt depends on libqtgui4 (>= 4:4.6.2); however:
  Package libqtgui4:i386 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package mrxt (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mrxt
```

Comment: Does `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -f` solve the problem? If not,  you will have to either solve the dependencies manually or file a bug report with wherever you got the .deb . What is mrxt and where did you get the .deb ? As much as possible you are going to want to install from software center or a ppa to avoid these sorts of problems.

Comment: Also 10.04 is way beyond EOL, upgrade to a supported of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Well, seems like mrxt needs some packages, too. You need to install them first.

Please try this

```
aptitude update && aptitude upgrade
aptitude install -y libqtcore4:i386 libqtgui4:i386
```

You also need `libopencv-highgui2.3` which doesn't seem to be in the lucid repositories. But it's listed in precise.